# Does the with block close the psycopg2 connection and cursor handle properly upon exit?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Consider the following 2 approaches:

**Manual close**

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=foo')
csor = conn.cursor()

csor.execute(qry)
conn.commit()

csor.close()
conn.close()
```

**With block**

```
with psycopg2.connect('dbname=foo') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as csor:
        csor.execute(qry)
        conn.commit()
```

My question is, are these 2 approaches equivalent to each other? I am concerned that the `with` block may destroy the references to the variables but leave the connections open. I do not think that this is the case though, based on some tests that I have run. However, it will be great if someone with more experience with these helps to confirm my understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement):

> When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been
>   raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of
>   exception the transaction is rolled back
>
> [...]
>
> A connection can be used in more than a with statement and each with
>   block is effectively wrapped in a separate transaction

So, no references are destroyed and no connection is closed, but a commit is done.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer! I definitely did not come across that section in the documentation when I was looking around earlier. Could you please also add in your answer that the **cursor gets closed** when the inner with block exits? I'll check it as answered thereafter.